# element positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling with the positioning of content returned from an AJAX call.

Here's an example of how my HTML is laid out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <section id="content">

    <div id="container">

      <div id="about">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia odit culpa excepturi itaque hic laborum odio nam deserunt ipsum dolor rerum repudiandae, quidem voluptatem nisi numquam tempora vel consequuntur harum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam ut error consectetur eum delectus porro dolore repellendus quidem! Ad, dignissimos minus debitis nam sunt aliquid eius quam cum, omnis magni. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe vero ducimus reprehenderit quibusdam esse sed, porro pariatur illum natus tempore? Iste laborum odio deleniti molestias praesentium delectus repudiandae consequatur corporis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est fugit provident, labore expedita nostrum laborum nesciunt! Assumenda inventore repudiandae dignissimos animi autem, dolorem sint, incidunt officia quam porro, perspiciatis fuga.
      </div>

    </div> <!-- end of content -->

    </section> <!-- end of container -->

  </body>
```

contact.html, bio.html etc... are all like about.html

And, here's the relevant css:

```
#container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;}

#contact {
        top: 30%;
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 50px 50px;}

 #about {
    transform: translateY(60%);
    background-color: red;
    padding: 50px 50px;}

#bio {
        transform: translateY(60%);
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 50px 50px;}

#gallery {
        transform: translateY(60%);
        background-color: green;
        padding: 50px 50px;}
```

The problem I have is when I try to position the content of the divs with id of "about", "contact", "container" etc... the divs won't get positioned. When I set the `top` property in contact to `30%`, the `div` just won't move and is stuck to the top of the page.

I have managed to position the other divs using `transform` but that seems a hack. What is the proper way of doing this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with AJAX.

If you wish to position element(s) with `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right`, the element(s) must also have their `position` property set (values can be `absolute`, `relative` and `fixed`) so that they are taken out of the normal document flow.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position for details.

Here's a simple example:

```css
div { 
  position:absolute; 
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.one {
  top:50px; 
  left:100px; 
  background-color:red; 
}

.two {
  top:150px; 
  left:50px; 
  background-color:green; 
}

.three {
  top:50px; 
  left:200px; 
  background-color:yellow; 
}

.four {
  top:150px; 
  left:150px; 
  background-color:blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="three">Three</div>
<div class="four">Four</div>
```